# Vim change color of cursor

Tags: vim

There's another question that asks this but the answer doesn't cover normal Vim.

I have

`set cursorline`

`hi Cursor ctermbg 172`

However, only the line number is highlighted orange, not the cursor block itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options depending on your OS, terminal program and if you are using Gvim.   Also look into predefined color schemes, currently I use '[flatlandia](https://github.com/jordwalke/flatlandia)'.

Using [Xterm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72797/how-do-i-highlight-the-current-line-and-the-cursor-in-vimrc)

Change it in [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230490/how-i-can-change-cursor-color-in-color-scheme-vim)

With [MacVim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312301/changing-vim-cursor-column-color-to-something-else-than-vim-background) (cross-hair)

Or [Gvim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158860/change-color-of-cursor-in-gvim)